Using Javascript to trigger a long running task
I have developed a component, and in one view a button can be clicked to invoke a task in the Controller. This task can take several minutes to run, so I'd like to be able to prevent the button being clicked again until the task has been completed.
I've tried various approaches in PHP, and concluded that if this can be achieved at all, it would be necessary to use Javascript. Ideally, the user should be redirected to a different page, and shown a message confirming the process had been started BEFORE the task itself begins. How can I go about it? Could I write an in-line script that includes the target id?
Invoking the task itself is simple "index.php?option=com_x&task=mailshot.send&id=n".

Is your com_x mailshot controller able to return a response that the task has been started and another response when the task has completed? I am thinking you could use the JS Fetch command to respond to your responses, if they are available, to disable and enable the submit button for your task.
